# Disable recent files in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

In Windows XP I could disable recent files somewhere in the Start Menu configuration. But I have upgraded to Windows 10 and it seems they removed that.

In Folder Options there are these entries:

- Show recently used files in Quick access
- Show frequently used folders in Quick access

Unchecking these only hides recent files in Quick access, but they are still stored in

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
```

Then I tried enabling this policy in gpedit.msc

```
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar\Do not keep history of recent opened documents
```

But it didn't work neither.

Is there an easy way of preventing Windows 10 from storing links to recent files?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In order to disable the recent items it requires 2 actions.

> 1. open `Personalization` in the `Settings` app.
> 2. Click/tap on **Start** on the left side. **Turn on or off to Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar** for what
>    you want.
>
> [image]

[Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3469-recent-items-frequent-places-turn-off.html)

You can also set the following registry key

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

Just set the DWORD **Start_TrackDocs** value to the desired setting

> 0 = Turn off
>
> 1 = Turn on

If you cannot find the key, it means you have not in the past toggled the option, doing so will create the key for you.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right-click desktop.
2. Click on *Personalize*.
3. Click on *Start* in the left pane.
4. Turn off *Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar*.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The two options above does NOT work. The links are still stored but just not shown, so in order to do it right, enable gpedit.msc and turn Off Recent Items Through Group Policy Editor.

https://www.howtogeek.com/236711/how-to-turn-off-recent-items-and-frequent-places-in-windows-10/

Comment: There is probably some bug that prevents option located in "PC settings - Personalization - Start" from working, unless you toggle corresponding Group Policy setting. Toggling it on&off fixed the bug for me, and Personalisation option works again.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the display in Window Explorer, when you look at a folder, then what you want is to disable all grouping in the folders view.

Go to the "View" tab, click on the "Group By" dropdown, and then select (none) as your option.

[image: Windows 10 Folder View Settings]