# How to clear Google Chrome recent files list

Tags: windows-10

Security-conscious users don't want a history of anything on their systems.
If you right-click the Chrome icon in the Windows taskbar, you will see local files that you may have recently used displayed in a vertical list. You have to remove this "recent" list manually, one by one. I have not found a tool that will clear them all simultaneously. I am using Windows 10. A Google search yields no results on how to "bulk" clear these items. With a large number of files recently accessed, this one-by-one method is not practical, and leaves an insecure trail of system activity. Does anyone know if there is a way to remove this "recent" list without having to delete the items one by one?

Comment: I think it's more of a privacy concern than it is security. If you don't want them to be stored, you may have to disable history altogether.

Comment: If you right click ***any*** icon on the taskbar of a program that can open files, it shows recent files. This isn't a browser or even a Chrome issue. This is a pure Windows 10 issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1031638/disable-recent-files-in-windows-10

Comment: The link to the possible duplicate has answered my question --> https://superuser.com/questions/1031638/disable-recent-files-in-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

This link to the possible duplicate has answered my question --> [Disable recent files in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1031638/disable-recent-files-in-windows-10)
I realize now that this is a Windows 10 function, not a Chrome function.
Thanks Moab and schroeder.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/465?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Use above link and follow the steps to clear chrome list activities

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.